# Changing all rows to have same data as first except for one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `df` like so:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
1   0   5   6   10  11  56  7
67  10  4   87  2   34  22  12
44  16  9   9   5   11  56  7
99  82  10  6   87  9   5   8
5   54  66  7   36  3   2   7
```

I want to change every row to be like row 1 except for the column x1.

My expected output would be:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
1   0   5   6   10  11  56  7
67  0   5   6   10  11  56  7
44  0   5   6   10  11  56  7
99  0   5   6   10  11  56  7
5   0   5   6   10  11  56  7
```

How can i do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[:, "x2":] = df.loc[0, "x2":].values
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
0   1   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
1  67   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
2  44   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
3  99   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
4   5   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
```

---

EDIT: For column `x4`:

```
x4 = df["x4"].copy()
df.loc[:, :] = df.loc[0, :].values
df["x4"] = x4
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
0   1   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
1   1   0   5  87  10  11  56   7
2   1   0   5   9  10  11  56   7
3   1   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
4   1   0   5   7  10  11  56   7
```

Comment: Would this work if I wanted to do the same for x3,x4,etc?

Comment: @Eisen You can save column to a copy and then assign it back. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.iloc[1:,1:]=np.nan#slice rows and columns to eliminate the first row and column and make them nan
df=df.ffill().astype(int)#forward fill the slice
print(df)

    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
0   1   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
1  67   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
2  44   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
3  99   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
4   5   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
```

Answer (score 0):

With **[`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)**:

```
cols = ['x1'] #change list as required ex: cols = ['x1','x2']
out = df.assign(**df.drop(cols,1).iloc[0])
```

---

```
print(out)

   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
0   1   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
1  67   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
2  44   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
3  99   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
4   5   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with row range `1:` assigned with row `0`. All operating on column range `1:`

```
df.iloc[1:, 1:] = df.iloc[0, 1:]



print(df)

   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8
0   1   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
1  67   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
2  44   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
3  99   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
4   5   0   5   6  10  11  56   7
```